# Group By with distinct in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this collection:

```
{
    "_id": "5b71c2ec3676d54422044a46",
    "resource": "/orders/4020283365",
    "user_id": 123453,
    "updated_at": "2018-08-13T17:42:04.000Z",
    "created_at": "2018-08-13T17:42:04.000Z"
}
```

I need to get the total of distinct `resource`,  grouping by `user_id`, like this:

```
{
    "user_id": 123453, 
    "total_orders": 231
}
```

I tried with this code, but it didn't work:

```
db.callbacks.aggregate([
    {$match: {'resource' : /orders\/.*/}}, 
    {$group:{
        _id:{
            user_id: $user_id, 
            resource: $resource
        }, 
        numberOforders:{
            $sum:1
        }
    }}
])
```

How can I get the total of orders grouping by `user_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query.

Use [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) to collect all unique values for resource field followed by [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to count the unique values.

Something like

```
db.callbacks.aggregate([
 {"$match": {"resource" : /orders\/.*/}}, 
 {"$group":{
     "_id": "$user_id", 
     "distinctorders":{"$addToSet":"$resource"}
 }},
 {"$project":{"total_orders":{"$size":"$distinctorders"}}}
])
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Now I have to figure out how can I make order by descendant total orders.

Comment: Yw. Did you mean to sort by total orders descending ?

Comment: Yes, because I need list the best sellers.

Comment: Add `{$sort:{total_orders:-1}}` after project stage.